# TCL multiple assignment (as in Perl or Ruby)

Tags: variables, tcl, variable-assignment

In Ruby or Perl one can assign more than variable by using parentheses. For example (in Ruby):

```
(i,j) = [1,2]
(k,m) = foo() #foo returns a two element array
```

Can one accomplish the same in TCL, in elegant way? I mean I know that you can
do:

```
foreach varname { i j } val { 1 2 } { set $varname $val }
foreach varname { k m } val [ foo ] { set $varname $val }
```

But I was hoping for something shorter/ with less braces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Tcl 8.5, you can do

```
lassign {1 2} i j
lassign [foo] k m
```

Note the somewhat unintuitive left-to-right order of value sources -> variables. It's not a unique design choice: e.g. `scan` and `regexp` use the same convention. I'm one of those who find it a little less readable, but once one has gotten used to it it's not really a problem.

If one really needs a Ruby-like syntax, it can easily be arranged:

```
proc mset {vars vals} {
    uplevel 1 [list lassign $vals {*}$vars]
}

mset {i j} {1 2}
mset {k m} [foo]
```

Before Tcl 8.5 you can use

```
foreach { i j } { 1 2 } break
foreach { k m } [ foo ] break
```

which at least has fewer braces than in your example.

Documentation: [break](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/break.htm), [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [lassign](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm), [list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [uplevel](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/uplevel.htm)

Comment: The order of variables is because that's what the old TclX extension used to do in its `lassign` implementation.